# What are the round screens show in the MOCR near position 19 (FDO?) during STS-49?

Tags: space-shuttle, mission-control

I noticed two very peculiar screens in the picture attached taken during STS-49, Endeavour's maiden flight. The screens are the round ones, and have text displayed. they are somewhat reminiscent of a CDC-6600 console, but are detached and much larger. They look a bit anachronistic, as they are next to a couple large workstation monitors and a laser printer (which seem stationed between positions 12 and 13).

Does anyone know what were those screens and what was being displayed there?

[image: Mission control during STS-49]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I asked my friend and former shuttle FDO Roger Balettie about this, he kindly gave me permission to quote him

> ..those are "Eidophor" displays - similar in nature to the much larger
>   versions back in the Bat Cave behind the 10x10 and 10x20 front
>   displays.  They were used early on in the Shuttle Program for the FDOs
>   to have clear overlays to put onto the projected ascent and entry
>   displays put onto those two GIANT round monitors.  I remember seeing
>   several FDOs having grease pens and marking the overlays up to
>   identify certain abort boundary call marks, or other important events
>   on the trajectory.  Then, as the mission events unfolded, they could
>   easily see their real time data and these easier-to-modify overlays
>   together.
>
> During orbit phases, we just used them as regular displays - giving
>   the FDO and TRAJ together 5 total displays to have up.  Plus, as you
>   can see, the top of the display case was excellent real-estate for
>   storage.

Roger's website about space, being an FDO, and the Trench is here: https://balettie.com/space/

Comment: I believe Roger is wrong on that one - eidophors were used on the large screens, but the round ones are Sanders Associates displays. They were large (for the time) 23" round CRTs coupled to a vector graphics generator reading vectors from RAM.

Similar displays are seen at http://bitsavers.org/pdf/sandersAssociates/CT-210_Sanders_Information_Display_Systems_Oct67.pdf on pages 7 and 18. Those systems had been in use at NASA since the Apollo days (although those two appear to be similar to their later Graphic7 system)

Comment: If you've got solid info, please post an answer @rbanffy